# Microsoft Word -> PDF image quality

Tags: image, pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

Our line of business application uses a Word document as a template, fills in the pertinent information and converts it to PDF, which it returns to the user.

That all works fine except for one thing. We use an image of our company's logo on the lead page and in the footer. In one resolution (e.g. 100%), it looks fine. But at higher resolutions (e.g. 250%), it has several noticeable jaggies; the diagonals have noticeable ragged edges. Tweaking the image, we're able to make it look good at the higher zoom value, but then it looks terrible at lower zoom values.

Currently, we're using a PNG, but we've tried JPG and it doesn't improve the jaggy problem. In fact, it looks worse at higher resolution because of JPG compression. I think a vector image would solve the problem (and we have the logo in vector format), but I haven't found any vector formats that Word supports.

I don't really have any code to show, since we don't do anything with the image in the code: we just take the document and plug in our values, none of which touch the logo (the template already contains the image).

We are using Word 2013 (32-bit) on Windows 8.1 (though some of our developers use Windows 7). We use the .NET PdfDocument class to generate the PDF.

Any ideas on how to get Word to be better at retaining image quality? Or is this a PDF issue?

Comment: How does the conversion to PDF happen? And what version of word are you talking about on what platform?

Comment: Using Word 2013 and Windows 8.1. Edited and added to question as well. To see "how" it happens, I'll have to dig through some code. I'll update when I find out.

Comment: We use the .NET PdfDocument class to generate the PDF.

Comment: The main reason I'm asking is to judge what you could use. For example, if the actual conversion is done with something like a PostScript or PDF driver, you could convert your logo into EPS and place it into Word like that. The printer would then convert that to good looking PDF.

Comment: If that's not an option, a vector format that is definitely supported by Word is EMF or WMF.

Comment: Besides that - and because Word is typically a big pain in the behind - it might be simplest to just create two versions of your logo, each at real size you need and insert those into the document. That sounds stupid, but the simplest solutions sometimes work best when dealing with MS Word.

Comment: It prints fine, but just because they always print the docs at 100% zoom. I'll see if we have better luck with EMF. Thanks!

Comment: Check the DPI of the image. If your desktop DPI is 96, then this image should also be 96. Then create a big version of this image and resize it down in your Word template.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! The stakeholders finally decided to go with the image that looks good at 100% zoom, because that's the resolution they'll print the contract with. I guess image scaling isn't Word (or Acrobat's) strong suite...

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion by David van Driessche might still work, provided the right EMF is used. EMF files can contain both raster and vector data. With a raster EMF file, the same problem will present itself as it did with PNG or JPEG. Vector EMF embedded in Word files can scale very nicely, at least when zoomed in display, so it could also work with printing or converting to PDF.
Word supports both raster and vector objects within EMFs, so the secret is to use EMFs that only contain scalable objects like lines, curves and text when quality & scaling are both concerns.

I have posted sample files [here](http://support.leadtools.com/SupportPortal/CS/forums/44791/ShowPost.aspx) to illustrate this for anyone wishing to see the difference.

Amin Dodin